# Изменение исполняемых файлов(css, js) через сайт

Tags: php, javascript, css

Здравствуйте! Есть сайт, и панель администратор. Надо реализовать возможность редактирования CSS и JS файла администратором, т.е. в панели администратора в инпуте находится код исполняемого файла (например: main.js), администратор меняет код и нажимает сохранить. После этого код в файле перезаписывается(как я понял лучше работать с файлом, а не с бд). Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: кажется наоборот через бд. Пишем инпут, кидаем в бд > в бд открываем указанный файл и записиваем то что пришло с инпута. сохраняем

Comment: @Horchynskyi, через файл, мне кажется, код будет быстрее работать + безопасность, но возможно я ошибаюсь). И в php есть функция `eval`, которая выполняет строку как `PHP` код, а как быть с `js` и `css`?

Comment: js не может менять файлы, только сервер php или node.js (или другой))
если вам надо именно перезаписать файл то точно только так думаю

Comment: @Horchynskyi, это понятно) Просто это я к тому, как потом выполнить `js` или `css` код вытащенный из бд?

Comment: ну файл же подключен к сайту, достаточно будет страницу перезагрузить и все поменяется

Comment: @Horchynskyi, я не про это. Допустим мы получаем данные из бд функцией `objectQuery`: `$object=objectQuery(); while ($row = $object->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $phpCode= $row['php'];
        }`. И выполнить этот код `eval($phpCode);`(если я не ошибаюсь). В случае, когда мне нужно вытащить `js` или `css` есть что-то на подобии функции `eval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для простого изменения содержимого файлов можно использовать `fopen`, `fwrite` и другие функции [для работы с файлами](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.filesystem.php).

**Пример записи**

```
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, '1\n');
fwrite($fp, '23');
fclose($fp);

// содержимое 'data.txt' :
// 1
// 23
```

**Пример чтения файла [построчно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13246674/2360072)**

```
$handle = fopen("data.txt", "r");
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
    echo $buffer;
}
fclose($handle);
```

Чтобы код в браузере отображался "красиво" можно использовать [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>installing code mirror</title>


  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.13.4/codemirror.min.css'>
 


<style>
body {
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 1%;
}

</style>



</head>

<body>
<h1>пример textarea для отображения кода</h1>
<p>
<textarea id="code" name="code">
  $(document).ready(
      alert('hello');
      $(".testbutton").click(function(){
          console.log("button pressed");
      });
  );
</textarea>


  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.10.0/codemirror.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.13.4/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.13.4/mode/xml/xml.min.js'></script>

<script>
var config, editor;

config = {
  mode: "text/html",
  indentWithTabs: false
};

editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), config);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Также рекомендую обратить внимание на библиотеки WYSIWYG для работы с обычными файлами.

Передавать данные из `<textarea>` на сервер можно с помощью AJAX на сервер и обратно в браузер.

Comment: похоже ваш вариант самый подходящий. Но возник вопрос, может ответите) Написал небольшой код для теста:   ` <?
$text = readfile('test.js');//получаю текст изменяемого файла 
 echo $text;?>// echo еще срабатывает нормально только в конце выводит длину строки
<textarea>// а textarea уже выводит только длину(. В чем может быть проблема?
    <?=$text?>
</textarea>
<?

$fp = fopen('test.js', 'w');
$newText = 'alert("Hello");';
fwrite($fp, $newText);

fclose($fp); `

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

 // Данный код - это упрощенный пример, для наглядности:

 // Создаете файл к примеру test333.php, помещаете этот код
 // В форме action указываем такой же файл-обработчик
 // Но естественно, вы можете сделать обработчик отдельно от хтмл

$path = 'test.js';

if (isset($_POST['save'])){


    $f = $_POST['code333'];
    file_put_contents($path,$f);


}


?>

<form method="post" action="test333.php">

   <textarea name="code333" style="width: 600px; height:400px;">

       <? echo file_get_contents('test.js') ?>

  </textarea>

<input type="submit" name="save" value="go" />

</form>
```